# Pass data to django form's field clean method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I have form like this:

```
class TitlePropose(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    code= forms.CharField(max_length=32)
    def __init__(self, contest, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TitlePropose, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.layout = Layout(,
            Field('title'),
            Field('code'),
        )


    def clean_title(self):
        if OtherModel.objects.filter(contest=contest, title=self.cleaned_data['title']).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Title unavailable")
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['title']
```

I try to access variable "contest" from clean_title method, without any success. I'm passing this variable in form class contructor:

```
#contest is just some object
new_title_form = TitlePropose(contest=contest.uuid)
```

Any suggestion, how can I get access 'contest' in clean_title?

Comment: See this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard Python class stuff. If you want to store an object so that other methods can access it, you make it an instance attribute by adding it to `self`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.contest = kwargs.pop('contest')
    super(TitlePropose, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_title(self):
    if OtherModel.objects.filter(contest=self.contest, ...
```